# How to show full image on click Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am new to Angular and I`ve spent a lot of time to find a solution but was unable to do so.
Idea is - there are two components, one for grid of photos and another for full image. I want to click on image in the first component and show second component with full image.
The problem is that I can not get the clicked photo to show up.
Images are coming from Unsplash API
Here is my service. First function is to get every photo and the second one to get the one which was clicked.

```
@Injectable()
export class ImageService implements OnInit {
  images: Image[];
  image: Image;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  fetchData(): Observable<Image[]> {
    let API_KEY = 'be469fc81f54e77afeaaccd5d4915f8bbe85c330d347f08213c0662735ec89ae';
      let options = {
        params: {
          client_id:  API_KEY,
          page: 1,
          per_page: 10
        }
      }
    return this.http.get('https://api.unsplash.com/photos', options)
                    .map(data => data.json() as Image[]);
  }

  getImage(id: number): Observable<Image> {
   return this.fetchData()
     .map(images => images.find(image => image.id === id))
 }

}
```

This is my detailed image component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail-img',
  templateUrl: './detail-img.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail-img.component.css']
})
export class DetailImgComponent implements OnInit {
  image:any;

  constructor(private imageService: ImageService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getImage()
  }

  getImage() {
    return this.image = this.imageService.getImage(
        +this.route.snapshot.params['id']
      )
  }

}
```

This is routerLink and the way I'm trying to show image

```
    <a [routerLink]="['/image', image.id]">
        <img src="{{image.urls.small}}" class="img-fluid">
      </a>

<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url('+image.id+')'}">
```

And this is my Image class

```
export class Image  {
  id: number; 
  link: string;
  color: string;
}
```

I think that the problem is in my `detail-img component` beacuse I get undefined when I try to `console.log(this.image)` but I don't know what to do with it.

Would appreciate any help because I confused myself with this task and have no idea how to resolve it.

How response from fetchData() looks like

[image]

Comment: your `getImage()` is either not called or you don't provide the code where it is

Comment: you meant get image() in the service? and why do you return a boolean in the component getImage() (yes the it return a boolean and doesn't set anything) ?

Comment: you're not subscribing to the image service.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include calling of getImage() in component. I call it in ngOnInit(){}

Comment: @bryan60 
I try to do this in my component. It returns undefined
`ngOnInit() {
    this.getImage().subscribe(image => console.log(image))
  }`

Comment: Thenupdate the question with relevant code please

Comment: remove "this.image ="  just after return in getImage()

Comment: @Vega Thanks, tried it, `image` still `undefined`